# Exception not being executed

Tags: java, exception

Im constructing a program in which the user inputs a height between 3 and 10 and a triforce from zelda is printed in java. At the current moment, whenever the user inputs numbers outside that range an exception is thrown, however I want the program to throw an exception whenever any string is inputted. Im not sure how to utilise the `InputMismatchException`. This is my code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int height;

    try {
        System.out.print("Enter height: ");
        height = keyboard.nextInt();
        }

    catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("Invalid height.");
    }

    if (height < 3 || height > 10) {
            System.out.println("Invalid height.");
            System.exit(0);
    }
```

Comment: You're asking for an `int`, if you want to check if a string has been inputted, then read in `Scanner#next` or `Scanner#nextLine` and use `Integer#parseInt` in a try-catch block.

Comment: You shouldn't use `System.exit(0)` in an "error" condition: exiting with a zero error code means "success", by convention. Moreover, you should use `System.exit` very rarely in code: `return` would have the same effect here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
try {
    System.out.print("Enter height: ");
    height = keyboard.nextInt();

    if (height < 3 || height > 10) {
        System.out.println("Invalid height.");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    // print triforce from zelda
    // ...
} catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("please input a int");
}
```

Comment: why do you catch `InputMismatchException` and use `System.exit`?